# How to Return String Content inside JSON objects Returned by json.loads() Function, insdead of Unicode Objects, in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

In want to convert a string to a JSON object in Python 2.7.
The example code follows:

```
import json

string1 = '{ "model": "UR32", "sn": "6218B1022170" }'

res = json.loads(string1)

print(res)
print(res['model'])
print(type(res['model']))
```

The results in Python 2.7 for above code is as follows:

```
{u'model': u'UR32', u'sn': u'6218B1022170'}
UR32
<type 'unicode'>
```

In Python 2.7, when the `json.loads()` is done, the contents of the object are converted to `unicode` objects, instead of `string` objects.

But,in Python 3, I get following results:

```
{'model': 'UR32', 'sn': '6218B1022170'}
UR32
<class 'str'>
```

Please see. It has resulted `string` objects. That is what I need. **I cannot use Python 3. I am coding a cellular router. Its Python SDK is only available for Python 2.7.** How can I get an string content inside my JSON object?

I referred to [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads).
It says as follows, which I cannot figure out what to do:

> json.loads(s[, encoding[, cls[, object_hook[, parse_float[, parse_int[, parse_constant[, object_pairs_hook[, **kw]]]]]]]])
>
> > Deserialize *s* (a `str` or `unicode` instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

> If *s* is a `str` instance and is encoded with an ASCII based encoding other than UTF-8 (e.g. latin-1), then an appropriate encoding name must be specified. Encodings that are not ASCII based (such as UCS-2) are not allowed and should be decoded to `unicode` first.

Please help me to find out how to avoid conversion of the JSON content to `unicode` objects and how to get `string` objects inside the returned JSON object by `json.loads()` function in **Python 2.7**.

Comment: Why do you need them to be `str`?  If there is any chance at all that your code will process non-ASCII text it's much better to work with `unicode` objects in Python 2.  NOte also that Python 3 `str` is the equivalent of Python 2 `unicode`.

Comment: I am combining these JSON objects and sending the final JSON object to a NodeJS backed website. In that website, I am retrieving data inside this final JSON using javascript. Since I am using string keys to retrieve values. I need these values to be strings before they reach the backend server.

Comment: I want to send data like this: {
  "wan": {
    "time": "5 days, 02:05:04",
    "wan_exist": 1,
    "mac": "24:e1:24:f1:6d:3c",
    "ipv6": "fe80::26e1:24ff:fef1:6d3a/64"
  },
  "lan": {
    "ip": "192.168.1.1/24",
    "connected": 0,
    "ipv6": "fe80::c863:54ff:fe37:dc45/64"
  },
  "wlan": {
    "status": 34,
    "cur_link": 0,
    "connected": 0,
    "mode": 0,
    "ssid": "Router_F16D3B"
  },
  "firmware": {
    "model": "UR32-L04AF-G",
    "sn": "6218B1022170",
    "hardware_ver": "V2.1",
    "firmware_ver": "32.3.0.3"
  }
}

Comment: Once serialised to JSON there will not be any distinction between str and unicode; the node site should accept the JSON generated by Python without error.

Comment: If I send it as of now. What I will receive will be like this: {u'wan': {u'ipv6': u'fe80::26e1:24ff:fef1:6d3a/64', u'mac': u'24:e1:24:f1:6d:3c', u'wan_exist': 1, u'time': u'5 days, 02:05:04'}, u'lan': {u'ip': u'192.168.1.1/24', u'connected': 0, u'ipv6': u'fe80::c863:54ff:fe37:dc45/64'}, u'firmware': {u'model': u'UR32-L04AF-G', u'sn': u'6218B1022170', u'hardware_ver': u'V2.1', u'firmware_ver': u'32.3.0.3'}}

Comment: Since I am transferring data through MQTT. The final big JSON object should be again transferred to 'str' and it should be converted from `str` to JSON again in the website backend.

Comment: `json.dumps({u'spam': 42})` -> `'{"spam": 42}'`

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb. I think this may help me. >Once serialised to JSON there will not be any distinction between str and unicode; the node site should accept the JSON generated by Python without error.

Comment: Thanks a lot @snakecharmerb. I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Python 2.7, the best thing is to continue with `unicode` content inside JSON. It will not affect you in any way.

If you need a neat string to send outside, just use `json.dumps()` at anytime when you need to send the JSON object outside the Python 2 program.

**Example 1**

```
import json

string1 = '{ "model": "UR32", "sn": "6218B1022170" }'

res = json.loads(string1)

print(res)

res2 = json.dumps(res)

print(res2)
print(type(res2))
```

Output:

```
{u'model': u'UR32', u'sn': u'6218B1022170'}
{"model": "UR32", "sn": "6218B1022170"}
<type 'str'>
```

**Example 2**

```
import json

wan = '''{
    "status": 1,
    "cur_link": 1,
    "ip": "192.168.254.20/24",
    "time": "5 days, 02:05:04",
    "wan_exist": 1,
    "mac": "24:e1:24:f1:6d:3c",
    "ipv6": "fe80::26e1:24ff:fef1:6d3a/64"
  }'''

lan = '''{"ip": "192.168.1.1/24",
    "connected": 0,
    "ipv6": "fe80::c863:54ff:fe37:dc45/64"
  }'''
  
wan_json = json.loads(wan)
lan_json = json.loads(lan)

final_json = {
    'wan': wan_json,
    'lan': lan_json
}

print(final_json)

final_string = json.dumps(final_json)
print(final_string)
print(type(final_string))
```

Output:

```
{'wan': {u'status': 1, u'cur_link': 1, u'ip': u'192.168.254.20/24', u'time': u'5 days, 02:05:04', u'ipv6': u'fe80::26e1:24ff:fef1:6d3a/64', u'mac': u'24:e1:24:f1:6d:3c', u'wan_exist': 1}, 'lan': {u'ip': u'192.168.1.1/24', u'connected': 0, u'ipv6': u'fe80::c863:54ff:fe37:dc45/64'}}
{"wan": {"status": 1, "cur_link": 1, "ip": "192.168.254.20/24", "time": "5 days, 02:05:04", "ipv6": "fe80::26e1:24ff:fef1:6d3a/64", "mac": "24:e1:24:f1:6d:3c", "wan_exist": 1}, "lan": {"ip": "192.168.1.1/24", "connected": 0, "ipv6": "fe80::c863:54ff:fe37:dc45/64"}}
<type 'str'>
```